# Using loops within an equation for Python and inputting values into QGIS

Tags: python, for-loop, pycharm

I would like to incorporate the use of loops within my Python coding equation. I am looking to find the value for the radius (distance) for multiple earthquakes and their corresponding intensity values. I am getting the magnitude and depth data from the USGS Excel Spreadsheet file. At the moment my code looks like this (see attached) but I would like to remove the Input MMI Intensity Value code and use a loop that runs intensity values from 0 to 12, in 0.5 intervals, into the equation.

```
ml = float(input("Enter Magnitude Value: "))
h = float(input("Enter Depth Value: "))
Iso = float(input("Enter Intensity MMI Value: "))
import math

Io = 1.5 * (ml - math.log(h) + 1.4)
a = (Io - Iso) / (1.8)
d = (10 / 8) * (a)

d = d - 1
if d <= 0:
    print("Distance is zero")
else:
    d = math.sqrt(h * h + d * d)
    print("Radius (km): ", d)
```

Once I have the distance for each individual intensity value, I would like to input these distances into QGIS, along with other Earthquake data, to create an earthquake hazard map that has radii rings of varying intensity around an earthquake point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range). As far as I know you cant use decimal numbers as step (with this range function) so divide by ten:

```
for Iso in [i/10 for i in range(0,125,5)]:
    print(Iso)

0.0
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
3.5
...
12.0
```

In your code:

```
ml = float(input("Enter Magnitude Value: "))
h = float(input("Enter Depth Value: "))
#Iso = float(input("Enter Intensity MMI Value: "))
import math

Io = 1.5 * (ml - math.log(h) + 1.4)

for Iso in [i/10 for i in range(0,125,5)]:
    a = (Io - Iso) / (1.8)
    d = (10 / 8) * (a)
    d = d - 1
    if d <= 0:
        print("Distance is zero")
    else:
        d = math.sqrt(h * h + d * d)
        print("Radius (km): ", d)
Enter Magnitude Value: 3.7

Enter Depth Value: 6.1
Radius (km):  6.565774088572565
Radius (km):  6.445404583784344
Radius (km):  6.341783476150495
Radius (km):  6.25574309025655
Radius (km):  6.188016815379507
Radius (km):  6.139210791849095
Radius (km):  6.109778451736456
Distance is zero
Distance is zero
...
```

Comment: Which section would I include this bit of code in? At the moment, I have replaced it with the "Enter Intensity MMI Value" code but all I get printed out is values for 0 to 12 in the dialogue, rather than individual distance (d) values for each intensity ranging from 0.5 to 12.

Comment: You say input in QGIS, you want to create a csv file and add that to QGIS?

Comment: Either a csv file or another file option that would allow me to create rings of intensity around an earthquake point (like a shakemap).

Comment: There is to much information missing in your question. For example what your table is looking like.

Comment: I agree there is quite a lot of missing information. To simplify it, not worrying about QGIS etc, I can input the depth and magnitude values myself in PyCharm. But, is there any way I can use that equation to get a value for d for varying intensity values (ISO), using a loop? Hope this makes sense and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is reasonable values for `ml` and `h`, I keep getting Distance is zero

Comment: For example, an earthquake that has a mag of 3.7 and a depth of 6.1km can be inputted into the equation and a Iso value of 2.5 would give a Distance of 6.14km. The bigger the earthquake and shallower the depth, the higher the Iso values in most cases.